# CoreImage coordinate system

Tags: ios, transformation, core-image, coordinate-systems, cifilter

I have `CVPixelBufferRef` from an `AVAsset`. I'm trying to apply a `CIFilter` to it. I use these lines:

```
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = ...
CVPixelBufferRef newPixelBuffer = // empty pixel buffer to fill
CIContex *context = // CIContext created from EAGLContext
CGAffineTransform preferredTransform = // AVAsset track preferred transform
CIImage *phase1 = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer];
CIImage *phase2 = [phase1 imageByApplyingTransform:preferredTransform];
CIImage *phase3 = [self applyFiltersToImage:phase2];

[context render:phase3 toCVPixelBuffer:newPixelBuffer bounds:phase3.extent colorSpace:CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()];
```

Unfortunately, the result I get have an incorrect orientation. For example, a video captured in the portrait mode is upside down. I guess the problem is in going from `AVAsset` to `CoreImage` coordinate system (showing a preview in XCode for *phase2* also presents an incorrect result). How to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out how to fix the orientation for portrait videos? I'm seeing the same thing and can't figure out if there's simply a setting that needs to be set

Comment: It was some time ago so I don't remember exactly, but I guess I hardcoded transformation like you did in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by doing this, It should orientate everything correctly to the coordinate space

```
var preferredTransform = inst.preferredTransform
preferredTransform.b *= -1
preferredTransform.c *= -1

var outputImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: videoFrameBuffer)
                    .applying(preferredTransform)
outputImage = outputImage.applying(CGAffineTransform(translationX: -outputImage.extent.origin.x, y: -outputImage.extent.origin.y))
```

Comment: Hey Jon, why is the translate needed? could it cause performance issues when doing it on many source frames? (filtering video for example)

Comment: Hi there, I don't think it should have a huge performance hit since you'll always do the preferredTransform. I didn't notice anything in my App when I implemented it.

Comment: Hey Jon! Applying the correct transform and then scaling the CIImage causing the image to render in a stretched-kind-of-way (for a portrait video). Do you have any idea what can I do to solve this?

Comment: Thanks for the working answer Jon, any chance you can elaborate what exactly this does and is there a more expanded version where we can read about this and why is this happening in first place? 